# Simple Application to make login in Android using Google, Facebook and Twitter

Tags: android, authentication, facebook-login

I'm looking for develop a simple application on Android to sign the user using either Google account, or Facebook account or Twitter account or a tipical registration inserting  few personal data from the user.
Do you have any suggest to do it? Where can I find an easy tutorial for each account?
My idea consist to develop a menu as a menu in this site to login on it but into a application android.
I hope to have been clear, this is my first time in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

WEll what you can do to create different menu Items for Facebook, Google , Twitter. Also you need sign-post library to sign your request. Suggest you to have a look through OAuth model.

Answer (score 0):

There are no any method by which you can be make own login window. For login you should be follow [this url](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/). There is the example and Facebook api by which we can login in Facebook and make own Facebook Apllication also.